# WPForms: How to set a default value in a dropdown by some Url param value

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to set default value in WPForms dropdown box taken from Url param value, given the dropdown has a fixed list of options?

So let's say I set this values for WPForm (either statically or dynamically):

- apple
- pear
- plum

now if I run page with the form by url ...&fruit=plum I want 'plum' to be pre-selected option

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing jQuery in Posts plugin and adding small jQuery script to the page, reading 'fruit' param value, selecting the dropdown by id and setting its value from script. Not very elegant solution, but at least it works. Does not look like WPForms let you do it out of the box, you can do it for textbox though, but WPForms developers forgot to implement similar feature for dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

We can handle the WP Forms fields using hooks. By using the wpforms_field_data hook we can Preselect the dropdown field based on our conditions. Sample code available in https://gist.github.com/akhileshpv/2671d6be15f75cc780617cb4c9efcc8b

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).